# Privileged / capabilities in a Dataflow container

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to run a Dataflow application such that the container it runs in will be privileged, or at least will have certain capabilities (such as `CAP_SYS_PTRACE`).

Taking the [top_wikipedia_sessions.py](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/complete/top_wikipedia_sessions.py) as an example, I can run it this way with Apache Beam:

```
python3 -m apache_beam.examples.complete.top_wikipedia_sessions \
  --region us-central1 \
  --runner DataflowRunner \
  --project my_project \
  --temp_location gs://my-cloud-storage-bucket/temp/ \
  --output gs://my-cloud-storage-bucket/output/
```

If I SSH into the created instance, I can see with `docker ps` that the started container is not privileged and has no capabilities kept (nothing in its `CapAdd`). I couldn't find any way in Apache Beam to control it. I suppose I could SSH into the instances and update their Docker settings, but I wonder if there's a way around it that doesn't require manually modifying the instances Dataflow starts for me. Perhaps it's a settings I need to update at the cluster settings of GCP?

Comment: If I understand your question, what you desire is to launch the container with something like `docker run --cap-add=SYS_PTRACE`. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct; only that I don't start the container on my own - it is started by Dataflow (IIUC). My question is how to ask Dataflow to do the equivalent of `--cap-add=SYS_PTRACE` :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way currently to directly modify the launch of the docker containers on a Dataflow worker.

However, [jobs with GPUs enabled](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/gpu-support) do run their containers in privileged mode. This has cost implications but could be a way to experimentally confirm that the feature addresses your need. If you can share more about the specific use case, perhaps it will make sense to generalize this feature to non-GPU jobs.

Comment: Thanks! In my use case, I'm trying to profile my Python application with py-spy, which requires SYS_PTRACE.

Comment: gcsfuse also needs privileged - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/issues/566#issuecomment-1088130787

Answer (score 0):

Since your goal is to profile you job with py-spy, have you considered and used Dataflow's profiling capabilities?

- [Docs on profiling a Dataflow Python pipeline](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/profiling-a-pipeline)
- [Essay on profiling Dataflow Python](https://medium.com/google-cloud/profiling-apache-beam-python-pipelines-d3cac8644fa4)
- [Docs on Cloud Profiler and Python](https://cloud.google.com/profiler/docs/profiling-python) in case you need to dig further
- [Essay on profiling Dataflow Java](https://medium.com/google-cloud/profiling-dataflow-pipelines-ddbbef07761d) could have useful info

Comment: Hmm. I will give it a try. But still, if it's anyhow possible to use py-spy I would prefer because we're fluent with it. I will continue looking into other options (e.g running py-spy from the Dataflow host as a privileged container)