# is it possible to use gcsfuse on dataflow workers?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, gcsfuse

With [gcsfuse's GA](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/storage-data-transfer/cloud-storage-fuse-now-ga), is it possible to mount gcs buckets (ideally by default) on the workers so that my c++ binary in a python dataflow job can access gcs with /gcs/my_bucket/my_file? This would be similar to what vertex ai etc has been doing.

Comment: Does this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494952/) help you?

Comment: it seems that the link suggest saving a copy locally, which is inefficient and error-prone.

Comment: Short answer: Yes but you need to use Dataflow workers with GPUs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70009476/privileged-capabilities-in-a-dataflow-container